# script# - need suggestion for wrapping extjs function definiton

Tags: extjs, script#

extjs uses an indirect class definition system. Here is an example

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'age',   type: 'int'},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'alive', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true}
    ],

    changeName: function() {
        var oldName = this.get('name'),
            newName = oldName + " The Barbarian";

        this.set('name', newName);
    }
});
```

I am trying to work out how to wrap this up in s#. Here is the exact thing I am tryiung to wrap

```
Ext.define('jslate.data.Proxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Client',
   constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent([config]);

        //ensures that the reader has been instantiated properly
        this.setReader(this.reader);
        this.dataManager = config.dataManager;
    },
    read: function (operation, callback, scope) {
        var me = this;
        me.dataManager.read(operation, callback, scope);

    },

    clear: Ext.emptyFn
});
```

I dont see how to do this - any suggestions? For example I need an arbitrary sized array of functions names and definitions, each function having any number of arguments. HOw do I get 'this' in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a "1:1" blind translation would look like:

*(assuming you have `[Import]`ed class(es) for Ext.data.proxy.Client and Ext.emptyFn)*

```cs
Ext.Define(
    "jslate.data.Proxy"
    new Dictionary(
        "extend", "Ext.data.proxy.Client",
        "constructor", new Action<Dictionary>(delegate(Dictionary config) {
            Client self = (Client)Script.Literal("this");
            self.CallParent(new Object[] { config });

            self.SetReader(self.reader);
            self.DataManager = config["dataManager"];
        }),
        "read", new Action<Object, Action, Object>(delegate (Object operation, Action callback, Object scope) {
            Client self = (Client)Script.Literal("this");
            self.DataManager.Read(operation, callback, scope);
        },
        "clear", Ext.EmptyFn
    )
);
```

---

Overall this seems like a tough conjoining of two different OOP paradigms & typing frameworks. However, I'd be curious to see if you could pull off something like:

*(assuming ExtDataProxyClient is `[Import]`ed, and `ICanInvokeParent` defines `CallParent()`)*

```cs
class JslateDataProxy : ExtDataProxyClient, ICanInvokeParent 
{
    public JslateDataProxy(Config config)
    {
        this.CallParent(config);
        this.SetReader(this.Reader);
        this.DataManager = config.Datamanager;
    }

    public void Read(Object operation, Action callback, Object scope)
    {
        this.DataManager.Read(operation, callback, scope);
    }

    public Action Clear = Ext.EmptyFn;
}

static class Utils
{
    public static void RegisterWithExt(Type t)
    {
        // extract fields, methods, constructor from type t. populate in a Dictionary(Object) 
        Dictionary typeSpecificationForDefine = ...;

        // invoke define
        Ext.Define(typeSpecificationForDefine);
    }
}

...

Utils.RegisterWithExt(typeof(JslateDataProxy));

...
```

I *suspect* you'll run into unexpected behavior doing this, but I admit I haven't delved deep into Script#'s and ExtJS's typing infrustructure to know for certain here.

Comment: excellent answer - tx. Could we chat a little via email to follow up on your second method (it matches what I was trying to do) paulmoore100@hotmail.com